# std::find on std::vector< std::string > does not compile in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl

I tried this code on Visual C++ 2008 express edition, but it does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    typedef std::string Element;
    typedef std::vector< Element > Vector;
    typedef Vector::iterator Iterator;

    Vector v;
    std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), std::string( "xxx" ) );

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
c:\programmi\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\algorithm(40) : error C2784: 'bool  std::operator ==(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
```

The same code is corrected compiled by gcc and works as expected.

Is it a bug of Visual Studio? And how can I get my example working on Visual C++ 2008?

Comment: You need to put the output of the error if you want people to look into it. Besides you don't populate your vector with anything, was it just to test std::find() ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <string>`.

You must always include all the headers that you need for your code. Never depend on magic recursive inclusions that happen to work sometimes. For everything you use in your code you must know where it has been declared and guarantee that the declarations are visible in your translation unit.

Comment: @Daniele In fact VS could really have helped you by choking on the first use of `std::string` in the typedef and not in some internal library function. So you're not more of an idiot than the VS compiler itself ;)

Comment: Looking at the code, not including <string> does appear to be a possible issue, but that really does not match the error message output which knows basic_string and therefore must be including string from somewhere. Why is it trying operator== on two vectors?